# Spline chart series not getting printed on export as image

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to export spline high chart as an image in my angular 4 application.I am able to see the burger menu when my chart is loaded after adding the reference in the app.module. I am also able to export the image by clicking on the burger menu and selecting png or jpeg options. The trouble i am having  while exporting the highchart the series doesn't get printed on the image. Do I need to write logic in the exporting section of the chart ?

The chart looks like this

[image]

Whats gets exported as image is

[image]

Spline chart component

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe, NumberPercentPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit';


@Component({
    selector: 'splinechart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
    chart {
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
         padding:0;
      }`]
})

export class SplineChartComponent implements OnChanges {
    static chart(shortNumberFormatPipe: ShortNumberFormatPipe, numberPercentPipe: NumberPercentPipe, translate: TranslateService, graphLegendTitle: string) {
        return {
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                margin: 25,
                itemMarginTop: 0,
                symbolRadius: 0,
                symbolHeight: 20,
                symbolWidth: 20,
                useHTML: true,
                title: {
                    text: graphLegendTitle,
                    margin: 50,
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic',
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            },
            //  exporting: {
            //     chartOptions: {
            //         legend: {
            //             allowHTML: true,
            //             enabled: true,
            //             margin: 25,
            //             itemMarginTop: 0,
            //             symbolRadius: 0,
            //             symbolHeight: 20,
            //             symbolWidth: 20,
            //             useHTML: true,
            //             align: 'right',
            //             verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            //         }
            //     }
            // },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.GRAPH_XAXIS')
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.GRAPH_YAXIS')
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return numberPercentPipe.transform(this.value);
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,

                formatter: function() {
                    let isMillionNumber: boolean = false;
                    const row = function(label, value) {
                        const key = 'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.';

                        return '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">' + translate.instant(key + label) + ': </td>'
                            + '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>' + value + '</b></td></tr>';
                    };

                    const transformNumber = function(value) {
                        isMillionNumber = validateMillionNumber(value);
                        if (isMillionNumber)
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 2);
                        else
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 0);
                    };

                    const table = function(format, point) {
                        let txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + '</strong><br><br>';
                        txt += '<table>';
                        txt += row('GRAPH_XAXIS', format(point.x));
                        txt += row('GRAPH_YAXIS', format(numberPercentPipe.transform(point.y)) + '%');
                        txt += '</table>';
                        return txt;
                    };

                    let point = this.points[this.points.length - 1].point;
                    return table(transformNumber, point);

                    function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
                        return millionNumber >= 1000000;
                    }

                },

            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    events: {

                        legendItemClick: function() {
                            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
                            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                                elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
                                elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
                            }
                            this.chart.redraw();
                        }
                    },

                    allowPointSelect: true,
                },
                spline: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle'

                    },
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    showInLegend: false
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    public options: any;
    chart: any;

    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public height: number = 400;
    @Input() public yaxisdata: any;
    @Input() public selectedRating: string = '';
    @Input() usedInPdf: boolean = false;

    private shortNumberFormatPipe = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();
    private numberPercentPipe = new NumberPercentPipe(this._locale);

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService, @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let graphLegendTitle: string = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE');
        if (this.usedInPdf) {
            graphLegendTitle = '';
        }
        this.options = SplineChartComponent.chart(this.shortNumberFormatPipe, this.numberPercentPipe, this._translate, graphLegendTitle);
    }


    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }

    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;

        this._redrawLogic(data.series.currentValue);

        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    public redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;

        this._redrawLogic(this.series);

        this.chart.redraw();
    }

    private _redrawLogic(series: any) {
        let seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for (let i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }

        series.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });

        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling there is something got to do with redraw or redraw method. When I add the directly to the series array in the template, it works fine

Comment: I have put console.log to print the series object in the map method and it prints the series to the console event during download. Then why isnt it gettting printed in download as image .  series.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
            console.log("The series object ",s);
        });

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. I had to set event = null under the exporting section

```
              chart: {
                        width: 1500,
                        height: 600,
                        events:null
                    }
```